# Адаптивное окно

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Здравствуйте!

Делаю форму заказа, столкнулся с проблемой, как её сделать адаптивной для разных размеров экрана.

Сама форма формируется путем помещения туда `html` через `js`. В `popup_text` помещаю что мне нужно. Стиль под каждый экран меняю так:

```
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <768) {
              $('.popup-content').css({'width': '80%', 'height': '80%'});
         }
         else if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <992) {
            $('.popup-content').css({'width': '60%', 'height': '60%'});
         }
         else{
            $('.popup-content').css({'width': '320px', 'height': '690px'});
         }
```

Все это можно посмотреть [здесь](http://testbl777.tk/) , нажав на кнопку заказать(блок, который висит слева). Базовый стиль задан так же для формочки с благодарностью(можете попробовать отправить данные, они идут на почту для отладки) и имеют размер `250px`, который смотрится хорошо на всех экранах.

Собственно, вопрос:

Какие стиле мне нужно задать `popup-content`, чтобы она хорошо смотрелась на мобильных/планшета/пк и т.д?
Долго эксперементировал, в итоге что-то запутался.

Спасибо.

Comment: А почему ты с помощью `media` не подстраиваешь?

Comment: @Yuri, у меня в одном и тоже блоке див разный контент. Можно задать через `media`, но  он будет для одной определенной формы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не хватает еще `overflow: auto;` для `popup-content`. Остальные параметры через медиа-запросы расставить. Например:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 600px) {
    .popup-content {
        width: 80% !important;
        height: 80% !importnat;
    }
}
```

Скрипт там вообще лишний. Разные параметры лучше применять именно в таблице стилей.

Comment: А `!important` то зачем использовать?

Comment: Сейчас на его сайте ширина и высота у элемента прописаны в `style`. Понятно, что это его скрипт задает эти значения, но если он попробует поставить у себя код из примера без `!important`, то ничего не изменится.

Comment: Понял. Желательно об этом упомянуть автору. Ибо, возможно, код просто скопипастится :)

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev, `overflow: auto;` и вправду решило проблему. У меня правда 1 вопрос возникл.
Я хоть и зада`z-ndex` больше, чем другие блоки, он их не перекрывает. Не соображу почему? Спасибо.

Comment: @ВладиславМСК у вас `popup-content` вложен в `popup`. Поэтому `z-index: 999` нужно задать именно для класса `popup`, тогда он перекроет остальные блоки.